# Can I replace 1 volt lights with 2 volt lights?

Tags: lighting, led, hood

The 1 volt LED lights in my range hood are going out and very dim, almost like a night light. Cheap hood. I cannot find replacement bulbs for these because the bulb cannot be removed.  The whole kit would need to be replaced.

IKEA has spotlights for under the counter that would probably fit in the same space.  I would like to buy the IKEA lights, cut off the connectors and replace with the connectors from the hood lights so that I can just plug them into the hood in place of the old lights without having to add a transformer.

The problem is that the IKEA lights are 2 volt, not 1 volt like the hood lights.   Will this even work?   Will the lights just be dimmer or would the transformer overwork itself?

Comment: Are you sure of your voltage measurements?  How do you know they are specifically 1 or 2 volt LEDs?  If an LED needs 2 volts, supplying 1 volt isn't going to do it.  Maybe you meant to say Watts?

Comment: I am pretty sure everywhere you've said "volt" you actually mean "watt". Red LEDs typically require at least 1.7 volts, and white require 3 to 3.5 V to even turn on; as far as I can tell 1 volt LEDs do not exist. Most range hoods are hardwired to 120V mains, and the vast majority use 120V standard edison screw-base bulbs (though some may take 12 volt MR16 bi-pin socket bulbs). Please confirm what you have (wattage, voltage, socket, and maybe provide pictures and/or model #s of the existing bulb and hood) and we can answer properly.

Comment: It says 12 volts DC in and 1 volt out

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No

There may be a way to redesign the circuitry but you are better off, in almost every case, to find replacement lights equivelant to what you are replacing.

Answer (score 2):

Something is super fishy here, LED's usually require a bit more than 1V especially the "lighting" ones. There are no "Bulbs" in LED's. LED's have very very long lifespans. I don't know LED's failure mode, but I don't think it's usually "getting dim" I think they usually just "go out".

I think the SMPS might actually be bad, which I'm sure is built into the hood. Long story short, an electrical engineer could "fix" this, anybody else is probably going to have to just replace the hood or not use the lights.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answers:

> Will this even work?

Yes, but it'll probably be worse than what you have now in terms of brightness.

> Will the lights just be dimmer...

Yes, they will.

> ...or would the transformer overwork itself?

No, a transformer is internally set at what ratio to step down the main voltage coming into it. It will always produce the same voltage output regardless of what is connected.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yes, it increases, but for all purposes necessary here - home improvement - it's unimportant other than to know that the bulb needs a higher voltage to push the demand load.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, the D in LED stands for Diode so yes, they have a diode like I-V curve. As an aside PWM dosn't really provide a "specific forward voltage" it only allows for a digital device to change brightness, (and sometimes there is a feedback, that allows it to optimise duty cycle)